# Camel bridging between HTTP and Https endpoint

Tags: java, http, https, apache-camel

Can I use Http Bridge endpoint feature to route from Http endpoint to Https endpoint? I use Servlet component.Please post in your suggestions. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, technically this shouldn't be a problem. However, maybe you should concern the security issues, e.g. see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server

Comment: yes peter it wasnt! thanks for helping me everytime!

Answer (score 0):

I did it without java, but with nginx, with the following version of `nginx.conf`:

```
events { }
http {
  server {
    root /mnt/gluster1/goujot/info/linux/service/nginx/root;
    listen 8888;
    server_name sloppy_http_mirror_of_https;
    location /s { # http://hostname.nosting.nginx:8888/s/project/gentooandroid/packages/packages/Packages
      proxy_pass https://downloads.sourceforge.net/;
    }
  }
}
```

It is necessary to update old version of gentooandroid.sf.net to newer openssl versions.
This only proxies the server (now TLS-only), here `downloads.surceforge.net`, of the newer openssl packages.
HTTP wouldn't be a big problem when dealing with my non-hostile LAN connections, but